# Trying to count the number of occurrances of each unique hour

Tags: python, counting

I'm trying to read in a file with two separate time formats and then count the number of times each hour of the second time format appears. This is my first Python script and am a bit lost after I thought that I was making significant headway. I'm getting the unique hours in my output file, but no counts and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I'd really appreciate any help that you could provide. Thanks!

**This is an example of my file-**

```
KABH, 11:17:00, 04:30:00  
KABH, 11:18:00, 04:31:00  
KABH, 11:19:00, 04:33:00  
KABH, 11:20:00, 05:34:00  
KABH, 11:32:00, 05:46:00  
KABH, 11:33:00, 02:47:00  
KABH, 11:34:00, 02:48:00   
KABH, 11:35:00, 02:49:00
```

**This is the code that I'm currently running to get the results-**

```
Python libs
import sys, glob, os, subprocess, calendar, string

# Input file
infile = "test.txt"

# Open file
fin = open(infile,"r")
data = fin.readlines()

# Lists to hold counts
stn = []
cnts = []
UTC = []
NST = []
HRS = []


# Loop over each line and count the number of times each hour is found
for lines in data:

d = string.split(lines,", " )
if not d[0] in stn:
  stn.append(d[0])
  UTC.append(d[1])
  NST.append(d[2])

t = d[2].split(":")
if not t[0] in HRS:
  HRS.append(t[0])

# Loop over all the unique times and count how the number of occurrences
for h in HRS:
  cnt = 0
  for l in data:
    t2 = string.split(l,":")
    if t2[0] == h:
      cnt = cnt + 1
  cnts.append(cnt)

# Open a file and write the info
fout = open("data.csv","w")
cnt = 0
while cnt < len(HRS):
 fout.write('%02d,%02d\n' % (int(HRS[cnt]),int(cnts[cnt])))
 cnt = cnt + 1
fout.close()
```

**Example of current output file-**

```
04,00
05,00
02,00
```

Comment: As your code is indented now it is wrong. Could you fix it? Otherwise we lose time with comments on what is badly indented.

Comment: Isn't it because when you compare `t2[0]` to `h`, `t2[0]` is the hour of the *first* time column, rather than the second? In your first loop in `for l in data:`, `t2[0]` is `'KABH, 11'`, not `'4'`, right? Right after you declare `t2`, print it and you'll see what I mean. You split the entire line by a colon, so `t2[0]` is everything to the left of the first colon. So therefore `t2[0] == h` always returns false, and `cnt` is never incremented.

Comment: @jphollowed you're totally right! I can't believe that I let that get by me. For whatever reason I thought that I was only splitting the third column, but I obviously split the string. Thank you for pointing that out. I knew that it was going to be something stupid and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dictionary` to save `hour` as key, create an empty list the first time a key is encountered and append 1 into the list. Finally, check the length of list for each key

```
counter_dict = dict()
with open("sample.csv") as inputs:
    for line in inputs:
        column1, time1, time2 = line.split(",")
        counter_dict.setdefault(time2.split(":")[0].strip(), list()).append(1)

for key, value in counter_dict.iteritems():
    print "{0},{1}".format(key, len(value))
```

The output is:

```
02,3
04,3
05,2
```

Comment: Wow. That is a much easier way than I was doing it. Thank you so much for this.